# Set ASP.NET Session variable from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to set a c# session variable from javascript:
I tried the following:

```
var mySearchPar = "search1";
<%Session["SearchPar"] = "' + mySearchPar + '"; %>;
```

but by c# instead of seeing the content of "search1" in the session I see `" + mySearchPar + "`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: WebForms or MVC?

Comment: I use WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your suggestions.
the result is this:

Sarch Html form:

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSearch" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSearchtxt" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-left: 0; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" onkeyup="Search(this);" placeholder="Search term...">
                <span class="input-group-btn" style="float: left;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSearch" runat="server" OnClick="Search_Click" class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Search(obj) {
        document.getElementById("hfSearchtxt").value = obj.value;
        var btn = document.getElementById('<%=lnkSearch.ClientID%>');
        btn.click();
    }

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
            var concept = $(this).text();
            
            $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
            $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
            document.getElementById("hfSearch").value = concept;
        });
    });
    
</script>
```

c#

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["SearchPar"] = this.hfSearch.Value;
    //search code body....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should store the value in a hidden `input` field and store it into the session on the next postback in the server sided code.

**Here is a little example:**

HTML

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSearch" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

JS

```
var mySearchPar = "search1";
document.getElementById("hfSearch").value = mySearchPar;
```

C#

```
// later in your click event:
Session["SearchPar"] = this.hfSearch.Value;
```

To be honest it looks like you want to store the last search term in the session. In this case, you don't need a hidden field, simply access the `asp:TextBox` on the click event and store the value in the session.

Maybe it's even better to not use the Session for such storage at all. Session will be stored on the server. Use cookies to persist the last search, instead. Cookies will be stored at the client and won't cost any resources of the server.

Comment: Yes, I thought but I do not even see Html components from C #

Comment: @SourazouSouryBountoulgou You have to use ASP controls, that have `runat="server"` on their attributes.

Comment: what you say works perfectly but does not do my case;
I use two types of filters:
-DropdownList
-TextBox
I need a Onchange event to textboxt 
so I have to go for javascript for:
1) store the master filter parameter (DropdownList to session)
2) remember to take the current textbox content and send it back to postback

Comment: Would it be okay to make a postback when the dropdown selection change? In that case, store the dropdown value in the session in code behind when it triggers the server sided change event by using `AutoPostback="true"` on the dropdown list. If your application does not find any session variable, it can assume the default value of the dropdown list. On your client sided change event of the textbox you can simply grab both values (textbox and dropdown list) and do your JS search.

Comment: If no dropdown postback is allowed, I suggest you to build an ASHX handler to perform your search and set the proper session variables. it could return JSON or XML with the results for you. This way the entire search logic and session handling is server sided, and you simply use AJAX to request it.

Comment: I also tried with ajax, I'm not mistaken but the request always fails

Answer (score -1):

In c# you can create a session variable using:

```
session["var"]="hello";
```

To display this value you can use:

```
Response.write(session["var"]);
```